# How to parse nested JSON from android?

Tags: android

I have the sample json data below. How can I parse it?

```
"posts": [12]
0:  {
"id": 6429
"type": "post"
"slug": "pyo-puth-remix-lyrics-dj-frenzy"
"url": "http://song.com/2016/06/remix-lyrics.html"
"status": "publish"
"title": " Remix Lyrics – DJ Frenzy"
"title_plain": " Remix Lyrics "
"content": "<p><strong>Remix lyrics</strong> is latest  single track produced by <strong><a >"
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not listen this guys in comments. You do not have to reinvent the wheel and implement your own Json parser. You can use any library for example [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi):

**Create Json representation:**

```
public class Dummy {
    int value1;
    List<InnerDummy> valueList;
}

public class InnerDummy {
    int value1;
    boolean value2;
}
```

**Use them to parse your Json:**

```
String json = "...";
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
JsonAdapter<Dummy> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Dummy.class);
Dummy dummy = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
```

Comment: This is the right approach